# IE8 "Refresh" button does HTTP GET twice

Tags: internet-explorer, http, internet-explorer-8

I'm developing embedded Linux device with web server built in. I use uhttpd as web server with LuCI as framework. The problem is the following:
When user press "Refresh" button of the browser (IE8) it sends HTTP GET request and starts to retrieve the response but this process is interrupted and the browser's screen dispays part of the page and some HTML markup text. After that browser sends HTTP GET again and retrieve the page without interruption.

When user just press to URL on the page and gets the page this behavior is not reproduced.

What is the reason of that behavior (GET twice)?

Comment: What does Lua have to do with this question?

Comment: I'm not sure does it influence or not, but uhttpd works tightly with Lua - it cache most used scripts in parent process to decrease the delay of responce.

Comment: Did you check to see if the two `GET` requests/responses are specifying different HTTP headers each time? My guess would be that IE8 starts downloading the first response and finds something it doesn't like about it so it aborts and sends a second request with different criteria to get different data back.